# What is "top-level HDL wrapper" means in Vivado SoC?

Tags: vhdl, vivado, soc

What is "top-level HDL wrapper" and why we need to do it in SoC project?

Answer (score 4):

You are right, normally in Vivado documentation it is explained how to generate it but not what is it. Well, I guess you use HLD languages (as for example VHDL). You know that you can create different `component` and you can `map` them in your top module HLD entity.

Here it is the same: you create a RTL project with your design hardware that needs to be connected to your target board. The WRAPPER is the file that connect the output/input port of your design to the physical pin described in the constraint file.

For example, if you create a simple design with a zynq processor, this one needs to be connected to the DDR, clock, IO_mio pins and so on. In this case, the wrapper should be something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VCOMPONENTS.ALL;
entity design_1_wrapper is
  port (
    DDR_addr : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 14 downto 0 );
    DDR_ba : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 2 downto 0 );
    DDR_cas_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_ck_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_ck_p : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_cke : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_cs_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_dm : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0 );
    DDR_dq : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
    DDR_dqs_n : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0 );
    DDR_dqs_p : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0 );
    DDR_odt : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_ras_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_reset_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_we_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_ddr_vrn : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_ddr_vrp : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_mio : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 53 downto 0 );
    FIXED_IO_ps_clk : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_ps_porb : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_ps_srstb : inout STD_LOGIC
  );
end design_1_wrapper;

architecture STRUCTURE of design_1_wrapper is
  component design_1 is
  port (
    DDR_cas_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_cke : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_ck_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_ck_p : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_cs_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_reset_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_odt : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_ras_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_we_n : inout STD_LOGIC;
    DDR_ba : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 2 downto 0 );
    DDR_addr : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 14 downto 0 );
    DDR_dm : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0 );
    DDR_dq : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 31 downto 0 );
    DDR_dqs_n : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0 );
    DDR_dqs_p : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 3 downto 0 );
    FIXED_IO_mio : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 53 downto 0 );
    FIXED_IO_ddr_vrn : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_ddr_vrp : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_ps_srstb : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_ps_clk : inout STD_LOGIC;
    FIXED_IO_ps_porb : inout STD_LOGIC
  );
  end component design_1;
begin
design_1_i: component design_1
     port map (
      DDR_addr(14 downto 0) => DDR_addr(14 downto 0),
      DDR_ba(2 downto 0) => DDR_ba(2 downto 0),
      DDR_cas_n => DDR_cas_n,
      DDR_ck_n => DDR_ck_n,
      DDR_ck_p => DDR_ck_p,
      DDR_cke => DDR_cke,
      DDR_cs_n => DDR_cs_n,
      DDR_dm(3 downto 0) => DDR_dm(3 downto 0),
      DDR_dq(31 downto 0) => DDR_dq(31 downto 0),
      DDR_dqs_n(3 downto 0) => DDR_dqs_n(3 downto 0),
      DDR_dqs_p(3 downto 0) => DDR_dqs_p(3 downto 0),
      DDR_odt => DDR_odt,
      DDR_ras_n => DDR_ras_n,
      DDR_reset_n => DDR_reset_n,
      DDR_we_n => DDR_we_n,
      FIXED_IO_ddr_vrn => FIXED_IO_ddr_vrn,
      FIXED_IO_ddr_vrp => FIXED_IO_ddr_vrp,
      FIXED_IO_mio(53 downto 0) => FIXED_IO_mio(53 downto 0),
      FIXED_IO_ps_clk => FIXED_IO_ps_clk,
      FIXED_IO_ps_porb => FIXED_IO_ps_porb,
      FIXED_IO_ps_srstb => FIXED_IO_ps_srstb
    );
end STRUCTURE;
```

Of course, if you open the file of your board-constraints you will magically discover that the signal-ports are all connected to the physical pins of the FPGA chip.